# Call number from QR code

Tags: android, iphone, ios, qr-code

I got a problem that seems unsolvable. The problem is in generating the QR code that will call one specific number. Number format is *103*14 digit activation number# and reading it with an android QR code application causes absence of hash sign (#) in call form. I googled it and the conclusion is that android API for some reason prevents reading hash sign from the QR code. Workaround for android OS is using URI encoding for hash which is %23, in that case it works like a charm. But reading the same QR code with the iOS QRReader application doesn't convert %23 to hash, instead it just shows 23. Is there a solution that covers all of these problems? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What QR-decode library do you use?
Are you sure you don't loose it when putting it to Intent?

Comment: The application that produces QR code is kind of a blackbox so we don't know which library is used. But, we tried reading it with several different QR code readers and the raw data that is read shows hash sign. Edit: We don't intend to write our own app for decoding the QR code, all we want is that QR code will be read the same on all platforms and QR code reader applications. (or almost all)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to double-encode the hash, so the percent sign is also encoded.

So, the # becomes %2523

Scan this QR code and your phone dialer should show *#67#

[image: URI encoded USSD Has QR]

See this [bug report on Zxing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/issues/detail?id=962)

Comment: Thank you, we tried that before, but on the iOs that will be *236723 ... obviously not what we wanted

Comment: Sounds like it's a bug with QRReader - may be worth reporting it to them.

Comment: Don't you mean `%25%23`?  That should translate to %#, what you have translates to #23.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you need to encode String before passing it to Intent:

```
String qrCode = "*103*14#";
String uri = Uri.encode("tel:" + qrCode);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, uri);
```